# Text book on solid geometry/stereometry, without involving analytic geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, 3d, book-recommendation

As the title says I'm searching for a textbook, about solid geometry, without involving analytic geometry. The material which the book should cover is the stereometry learned in the eastern bloc. An example of such book is [Kisele's Geometry / book II Stereometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977985210).

However I'm having hard time learning this subject, and this books doesn't seems to be for me (I take a look at the first few characters and I was unable to understand the material. I have a textbook, from which we study in class, however I'm unable to understand it also, and half of the exercises are with wrong answer. On other hand I'm ashamed and afraid to ask my teach for help when needed, since we already passed this material in school, and I got a decent grade, not sure how I managed to solve the exercises on the test.

Comment: You should never be ashamed to ask your teacher for advice on what material might help you get a better understanding of some aspect of a subject he has taught you.  Explain the situation with the textbooks you have found being unreadable or incorrect; he probably has a good suggestion.  And any good teacher likes this sort of question from a student, it makes him feel he has inspired the student to wish to delve further into the subject.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, actually he knows about the wrong answers, mainly because usually I'm the wrong one, not the writer of the book, so I ask him, and he confirms about the mistake( I will report them when I finish the material). But as I said I have almost no idea how to solve most of the exercises involving thinking without using google, this site or help from somebody.

Comment: What languages can you read?

Comment: English and Bulgarian

Comment: I expect you'll find much more written in or translated into Bulgarian than in English. Solid geometry hasn't been taught at a high level in the schools of English-speaking countries for a long time. I know of a few good books in Russian and French, but a glance at the catalogue of the Bulgarian National Library shows they don't appear to have been translated into Bulgarian.

Comment: Well every 12 grade math textbook covers the material, I have looked at a few other textbooks and it looks like they were written by the same person.

Comment: Here is a bibliography on solid geometry: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolidGeometry.html I don't know any of those books (except for a passing acquaintance with the one by Rouché and Comberousse), but I know Altshiller-Court and Cohn are good writers. There's also the book *Problems in Solid Geometry* by Sharygin, translated from Russian.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the World War 2 Education Manual EM310 Solid Geometry.  It can be ordered on Amazon for a very reasonable price.

Content is explicitly designed for self-instruction, with answers provided--consider the intended audience.  It covers the topics you want and does so without analytic geometry:  is intended to be in the curriculum after plane geometry and prior to "college algebra".

[https://www.amazon.com/Solid-Geometry-310-M-Welchons/dp/B001CZ0V88](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CZ0V88)

I actually bought the paperback since I knew that was the War Department version of the classic text.  Wanted it because had lost copy of my father (who served in WW2).  Plus I knew the War Department version would have all the answers.

You could try the hardcover, maybe it has the answers and is OK for self teaching also, don't know.  Actually back in the dark age, it was normal for math books to have all the answers.  It is only in recent times that we have regressed to not having these in book.